# EPROTOTYPE (_SIGN 41 ) while creating raw socket() in MINIX 3

Tags: networking, socket, programming, unix-sockets, minix

The following is my code snippet that is producing `EPROTOTYPE` error, aka, `Protocol Wrong Type for Socket`.

I checked for the headers in `/usr/include` in MINIX 3, `sys/socket.h` contains definitions for `AF_INET` and `SOCK_RAW`, and declaration for `socket()` while `netinet/in.h` contains the definition for `IPPROTO_RAW`. I carefully included both the headers in my file still no luck.

```
   // Open internal socket    
        int raw_internal_1 =0; 
        raw_internal_1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW); 
        if(raw_internal_1 < 0){
            perror("Error[01]: Unable to create socket");
            return 1;
        }
```

Error simply shows: `Protocol Wrong Type for Socket`.

This error is defined in `/sys/sys/errno.h` as `#define EPROTOTYPE (_SIGN 41 ) /* Protocol wrong type for socket */`
The MINIX `man socket(2)` says `[EPROTOTYPE] The protocol is not supported by the domain.`

The same code runs fine on Linux distros - Ubuntu, & Arch. However, due to my project domain limitations, I will, unfortunately, have to stick with Minix.

Any suggestions will be saving me from further frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firing up a Minix VM, `man 2 socket` brings up the manual page for the `socket` function.  Its description is as follows:

> `socket()` creates a socket in the specified *domain*. […] Currently two values are supported for *domain*, `PF_INET` for internet sockets and `PF_UNIX` for local unix domain sockets. The *type* of the socket can be `SOCK_STREAM` for TCP sockets in the `PF_INET` *domain* or `SOCK_DGRAM` for UDP sockets in the `PF_INET` *domain*. […] The value of *protocol* is always 0 or `IPPROTO_TCP` for TCP sockets or `IPPROTO_UDP` for UDP sockets.

I elided only material about the `PF_UNIX` *domain*. You may note that unlike the manuals for Linux or macOS, there is no mention of `SOCK_RAW`. This implies to me that raw sockets are not (yet?) fully supported in Minix in the same way as on some other systems.

Digging into the source code itself, one finds in `minix/lib/libc/sys/socket.c` the following:

```c
if (domain == AF_INET && sock_type == SOCK_RAW && protocol == IPPROTO_ICMP)
        return _raw_socket(type, protocol);
if (domain == AF_INET && sock_type == SOCK_RAW && protocol == IPPROTO_UDP)
        return _raw_socket(type, protocol);
```

Thus for those two protocols, and those two alone, you can get a raw socket.  Indeed your code compiles and runs without error if `IPPROTO_RAW` is replaced by either `IPPROTO_UDP` or `IPPROTO_ICMP`.

Comment: This solves the problem, partially, for my project, however, I will need one more help regarding a similar issue, if it is okay? I have posted the query [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712644/enosys-sign-38-while-bind-raw-socket-in-minix-3)